# Hibernate mapping multiple entities to one

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two models, `Account` and `Transaction`. The `Account` looks as follows:

```
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private BigDecimal balance;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Transaction> transactions;

    public Account(final BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        this.transactions.add(transaction);
    }
}
```

The `Transaction` entity is as follows:

```
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Account sender;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Account recipient;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    public Transaction(Account sender, Account recipient, BigDecimal amount) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

As you can see, a `Transaction` is between a `Sender` and `Recipient`, both of these are represented by the `Account` entity. In this case, a `Transaction` will have a One-To-One mapping for a Sender and the same for a Recipient. However, on the flip side, the `Account` entity should be able to represent all transactions from an account regardless of whether it is a sender or receiver. Using the above mapping allows me to insert transactions, however I am unable to get it back on the mapping. In essence, I am not sure what the best annotations to use are in this case.

I should add, that using the above code, I get the following hibernate error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.xxx..Account from com.xxx.Transaction has the wrong number of column. should be 1
```

Comment: I would totally omit the `Account.transactions` side of the relationship and fetch the transactions of an account with something like `SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE t.sender=:account OR t.recipient=:account` (JPQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that an `Account` can be the sender/receiver in multiple transactions:

1. Sender and Receiver are actually a `@ManyToOne`:

   ```
   public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Account sender;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Account recipient;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    public Transaction(Account sender, Account recipient, BigDecimal amount {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
   }
   ```

   That's because a single `Account` can be the sender for many transactions, but a single `Transaction` can only have a sender. The same for the receiver.
   I'm also assuming that all the transactions must have a sender and receiver.
2. `@OneToMany` to two different colums.

   You are creating a one-to-many in `Account`, but which column do you expect to map the association on the `Transaction`? Because there are two possible columns containing an account, Hibernate ORM doesn't know which one to use and throws an exception.

Removing the association from `Account` should solve your issue:

```
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private BigDecimal balance;

    public Account(final BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

When you need all the transactions for a specific account you can run the following JPQL query. For example, using the EntityManager:

```
entityManager
    .createQuery("FROM Transaction t WHERE t.sender=:account OR t.recipient=:account")
    .setParameter("account", account )
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: That makes sense, however, I tried another approach which is to have a `@OneToOne` mapping on both sender and recipient in `Transaction` and instead created two lists in `Account`: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "sender") List<Transaction> sender_transactions` and the same for recipient transactions. In this case, I then created a Transient field which combines these two lists when querying for all transactions in `Account` and this seems to work fine. However, I am wondering if it is good practice to do it this way or as suggested just one mapping...

Comment: You need two separate queries and then have to combine the results. It seems a lot of extra work that you could avoid with a single query to the db. But it is up to you. You still need to change the mapping to `@ManyToOne` (instead of `@OneToOne`), if an account can be the sender/receiver for more than one transaction.